# monthly active user Analysis - How to display a month when 0 events have occured

Tags: sql

I have a table like so

```
User| Action | Date
1     log-in   2021-07-08
1     log-in   2021-09-03
...
```

And so on...

What I want is to be able to see how many uses user 1 used each month since joining, even the month where he didn't do anything kind of like this:

```
User|   Cohort    |   Date   | Clicks
1     2021-07-01   2021-07-01    1
1     2021-07-01   2021-08-01    0
1     2021-07-01   2021-09-01    1
...
```

to do that I have done something like:

```
with cte as (
select user, max(date_trunc('month',date)) as this_month
from table
group by 1
having max(date_trunc('month',date)) = date_trunc('month',Current_date)
)

select t.user, cte.this_month, date_trunc('month',t.date), count(*) as clicks
from table t
join cte on cte.user = t.user
group by 1,2,3
order by 1,3 desc
```

But that skips August, only showing July and September.

Any recommendations?

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks like Postgres.  If so, you can use `generate_series()`:

```
select t.user, t.cohort, gs.date,
       count(*) filter (where date_trunc('month', date) = gs.date) as clicks
from (select t.*,
             date_trunc('month', min(date) over (partition by user)) as cohort
      from t
     ) t cross join lateral
     generate_series(t.cohort, current_date, interval '1 month') as gs(date)
group by t.user, t.cohort, gs.date
```